# Converting decimal String to Double give wrong Double

Tags: ios, swift, string, double

I try to convert a String decimal like "1.10" to Double object but
when I use

```
    Double("1.10") result is wrong 1.1000000000000001
```

but if I use

```
    Double("1.02") result is ok : 1.02
```

Did i miss something ?

I use the simulator iPhone XS in Swift 5.0 and Xcode 10.1

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/why-do-inaccuracies-occur-in-floating-point-math-operations

Comment: What you are missing is that `Double` is a *binary* floating point number, and cannot represent all numbers exactly.